# Can I highlight an equal sign after a pause in beamer latex environment?

Tags: beamer, equations, align, pause

I am working on a beamer presentation with latex. I have a set of equations and I am wondering if there is a way for me to show all the equations and after a pause, circle the last equality sign to point something about it to my audience. I attach two pictures. In the first picture, I show the set of equalities (with the code), and I would like to then have a pause and circle the last equality.

```
\begin{align*}
   E\left(Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)\right)\Pause&=E\left(Y(1)-Y(0)\right) 
   \\&= E(Y(1))-E(Y(0))
   \\&=E(Y|T=1)-E(Y|T=0)
\end{align*}
```

[image]

(Would like a Pause here)

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: Replace all instances of `|` in the code above with `\mid `. That way, you'll get the spacing that's appropriate for a relational operator.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the macro `\Pause` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `hf-tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\hfsetfillcolor{bg}
\hfsetbordercolor{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
   E\left(Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)\right)&=E\left(Y(1)-Y(0)\right) 
   \\&= E(Y(1))-E(Y(0))
   \\&\tikzmarkin<2->{a1}=\tikzmarkend{a1}E(Y|T=1)-E(Y|T=0)
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @StivenG You're welcome!